# Sum array column with conversion of that array column

Tags: php, arrays

I want to create a accounting system. I insert all the information that I need into array but I have a problem showing the data in the array.

My accounting system has different ways to pay and the `deposit_price` column in the array has all the ways separated by a comma (`,`).

The array looks like this:

```
$array = [
    array(
            'deposit_id' => 317,
            'deposit_date' => '1398/9/21',
            'deposit_price' => '40,0,14',
            'deposit_code' => 1111,
            'deposit_gender' => 0,
            'deposit_phone_send' => '09124139155',
            'deposit_how_get' => '',
            'deposit_user_select' => 'user 2',
            'deposit_for' => '3dmax',
            'deposit_status' => 0,
            'deposit_description' => 'null',
            'deposit_abutment_id' => 52
        ),

       array(
            'deposit_id' => 400,
            'deposit_date' => '1398/9/22',
            'deposit_price' => '20,10,0',
            'deposit_code' => 2431,
            'deposit_gender' => 1,
            'deposit_phone_send' => '09102781932',
            'deposit_how_get' => '',
            'deposit_user_select' => 'user 2',
            'deposit_for' => 'Autocad',
            'deposit_status' => 0,
            'deposit_description' => 'null',
            'deposit_abutment_id' => 55
        ),

];
```

I want to sum the individual values in the `deposit_price` for all types of payments for each element in the array like this.

```
<!--
Cash deposit = sum all member `deposit column` prior to the first `,`; that meaning 60 for this example
Card deposit = sum all member `deposit column` between the first and second `,`; that meaning 10
POS deposit = sum all member `deposit column` after the second `,`; that meaning 14
all deposit = sum all values in the `deposit_price` column; that meaning 84

I want to show these values in html like this:
-->

<h2>Cash deposit<h2>
<p>60</p>

<hr>

<h2>Card deposit<h2>
<p>10</p>

<hr>

<h2>POS deposit<h2>
<p>14</p>

<hr>

<h2>all deposit<h2>
<p>84</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_reduce`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) to compute an array of all the sums of the different values in the `deposit_price` column of the array, and then iterate over that array to get the output that you want:

```
$deposits = array_reduce($array, function ($c, $v) {
    list($cash, $card, $POS) = explode(',', $v['deposit_price']);
    $c['Cash'] += $cash;
    $c['Card'] += $card;
    $c['POS'] += $POS;
    return $c;
}, array('Cash' => 0, 'Card' => 0, 'POS' => 0));

foreach ($deposits as $type => $value) {
    echo "<h2>$type deposits</h2>\n<p>$value</p>\n<hr>\n";
}
echo "<h2>All deposits</h2>\n<p>" . array_sum($deposits) . "</p>\n<hr>\n";
```

Output:

```
<h2>Cash deposits</h2>
<p>60</p>
<hr>
<h2>Card deposits</h2>
<p>10</p>
<hr>
<h2>POS deposits</h2>
<p>14</p>
<hr>
<h2>All deposits</h2>
<p>84</p>
<hr>
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/rgk82)

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple `foreach` loop like below:

```
$res['Cash'] = 0;
$res['Card'] = 0;
$res['POS'] = 0;
$res['All'] = 0;

foreach($array as $data){
    $dep = explode(',',$data['deposit_price']);
    $res['Cash'] += $dep[0];
    $res['Card'] += $dep[1];
    $res['POS'] += $dep[2];
    $res['All'] += array_sum($dep);
}

foreach ($res as $nam => $val) {
    echo "<h2>".$nam." deposits</h2>".PHP_EOL."<p>".$val."</p>".PHP_EOL."<hr>".PHP_EOL;
}
```

Outputs:

```
<h2>Cash deposits</h2>
<p>60</p>
<hr>
<h2>Card deposits</h2>
<p>10</p>
<hr>
<h2>POS deposits</h2>
<p>14</p>
<hr>
<h2>All deposits</h2>
<p>84</p>
<hr>
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/oWEVt)**